# Redisplay Form with Previously Submitted Data on Error in Django

Tags: html, django, forms

How do I get the submitted data to re-display in a formset after it encounters an error?  Django book talked about this and I was able to make it work in a form but not in a formset.

Scenario:
There are 2 required fields - First name and last name.  If I only entered 'John' in the first name field leaving the last name field empty and click submit, I will get an error saying that both fields are required and the form cleared the submitted data with the error message.  I want to see the name 'John' in the first name field along with the error messages.

Much appreciated!

```
**forms.py**

from django import forms
from django.forms.formsets import BaseFormSet


class NameForm (forms.Form):

    first_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)
    last_name = forms.CharField (max_length = 20, required = False)


class BaseNameFormSet (BaseFormSet):

    def clean (self):
        if any (self.errors):
            return

        firstnames = []
        lastnames = []
        for form in self.forms:
            firstname = form.cleaned_data.get ('first_name')
            lastname = form.cleaned_data.get ('last_name')

            if (firstname in firstnames) or (lastname in lastnames):
                raise forms.ValidationError ('First or last name must be unique')
            if (firstname == '') or (lastname == ''):
                raise forms.ValidationError ('Both first and last name must be filled out')

            firstnames.append (firstname)
            lastnames.append (lastname)

        return self.cleaned_data


**views.py**

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms.formsets import formset_factory
from nameform.forms import NameForm
from nameform.forms import BaseNameFormSet
from nameform.addName import webform


# Create your views here.
def addname (request):

    # Set maximum to avoid default of 1000 forms.
    NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, formset = BaseNameFormSet, extra = 2, max_num = 5)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Django will become valid even if an empty form is submitted. Adding initial data causes unbound form and
        # trigger formset.errors
        # formset = NameFormSet (request.POST, initial = [{'first_name': 'John', 'last_name': 'Doe'}])
        formset = NameFormSet (request.POST)

        if formset.is_valid ():
            location = request.POST ['site']
            data = formset.cleaned_data

            for form in data:
                # Retrieving the value in an empty dictionary will result key error as it doesn't exist
                # firstname = form ['first_name']
                # lastname = form ['last_name']

                firstname = form.get ('first_name')
                lastname = form.get ('last_name')

                if firstname and lastname:
                    webform (firstname, lastname, location)

            context = {'data': data, 'location': location}

            return render (request, 'nameform/success.html', context)

    else:
        formset = NameFormSet ()

    return render (request, 'nameform/addname.html', {
        'formset': formset,
        'first_name': request.POST.get ('first_name', ''),
        'last_name': request.POST.get ('last_name', '')
    })


**addname.html**

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Add Name</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Add Name</h1>
    <form action="" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
        <h3>Location:</h3>
        <p><input type="radio" id="radio1" name="site" value="Location_A" checked>
        <label for="radio1">Location A</label>
        <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="site" value="Location_B">
        <label for="radio2">Location B</label></p>
        {{ formset.management_form }}
        <label for="id_form-0-first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input id="id_form-0-first_name" maxlength="20" name="form-0-first_name" type="text" value="{{ first_name }}" />
        <label for="id_form-0-last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input id="id_form-0-last_name" maxlength="20" name="form-0-last_name" type="text" value="{{ last_name }}" />
        <p><label for="id_form-1-first_name">First Name:</label>
        <input id="id_form-1-first_name" maxlength="20" name="form-1-first_name" type="text" value="{{ first_name }}" />
        <label for="id_form-1-last_name">Last Name:</label>
        <input id="id_form-1-last_name" maxlength="20" name="form-1-last_name" type="text" value="{{ last_name }}" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Add Name"></p>
    </form>

    {% if formset.errors %}
    <p style="color: red;">Please correct the error below:</p>
    {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
    {% endif %}

</body>
</html>
```

[image: Form]

**In Shell:**

```
>>> partial_data = {
...     'form-TOTAL_FORMS': '2',
...     'form-INITIAL_FORMS': '0',
...     'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '3',
...     'form-0-first_name': 'John',
...     'form-0-last_name': 'Doe',
...     'form-1-first_name': 'James',
...     'form-1-last_name': ''
... }
>>> 
>>> NameFormSet = formset_factory (NameForm, formset = BaseNameFormSet)
>>> formset = NameFormSet (partial_data)
>>> 
>>> formset.is_valid ()
False
>>> formset.errors
[{}, {}]
>>> formset.non_form_errors ()
['Both first and last name must be filled out']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turned out, I need to make the changes below.  The key here is to associate the "first_name_0" variable with the input field in html, "form-0-first_name".  If you make both variable and the name of the html input box the same, you will get an error.

For example:

```
return render (request, 'nameform/addname.html', {
        'formset': formset,
        'form-0-first_name': request.POST.get ('form-0-first_name', '')})
```

Django doesn't like that format.  Instead make it the same with what I have below to match which input field with the variable.

**views.py**

```
...
...
...
    return render (request, 'nameform/addname.html', {
        'formset': formset,
        'first_name_0': request.POST.get ('form-0-first_name', ''),
        'last_name_0': request.POST.get ('form-0-last_name', ''),
        'first_name_1': request.POST.get ('form-1-first_name', ''),
        'last_name_1': request.POST.get ('form-1-last_name', '')
```

**addname.hmtl**

```
   ...
    ...
    ...
    {{ formset.management_form }}
            <label for="id_form-0-first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input id="id_form-0-first_name" maxlength="20" name="form-0-first_name" type="text" value="{{ first_name_0 }}" />
            <label for="id_form-0-last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input id="id_form-0-last_name" maxlength="20" name="form-0-last_name" type="text" value="{{ last_name_0 }}" />
            <p><label for="id_form-1-first_name">First Name:</label>
            <input id="id_form-1-first_name" maxlength="20" name="form-1-first_name" type="text" value="{{ first_name_1 }}" />
            <label for="id_form-1-last_name">Last Name:</label>
            <input id="id_form-1-last_name" maxlength="20" name="form-1-last_name" type="text" value="{{ last_name_1 }}" /></p>
```

**The desired result:**

Now the user know what they did wrong or what was missing without refilling the whole form.

[image: Add_Name]

Answer (score 0):

formsets are exactly the same as forms, just load it with the request.POST.

here is some code in one of my projects.

```
formset = modelformset_factory(PaymentTemplates, extra=extras, form=PaymentTemplateForm)
    if request.POST:
        formset = formset(request.POST)
```

in your template:

```
{% if formset.total_error_count %}
    <ul class="errorList">
    {% for dict in formset.errors %}
        {% for error in dict.values %}
        <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

i assume you also know that you need this:

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

look up how to render forms manually,
or use something like crispy forms, or django-bootstrap3 which has template tags to handle all this.

Comment: How do you get your formset to display the previously submitted data?  My formset is working like it should but not sure how to redisplay user's input on errors.

Comment: the form should be populated with whatever the user imputed (that's what formset(request.POST) does), with the error showing wherever you set the error code.

Comment: I appreciate your input warath, but that's not what I'm trying to accomplish.  Your method above is just another way of displaying the errors similar to what I've shown in the images.  What I wanted to see is the first name input box to show "John".  It is so the user doesn't have to retype the names and know what to fix after the error is shown.

Comment: @dreamzboy i expanded my example. all the users input is saved in the formset forms, so can be accessed.